# SIP js UserAgent API, I don't kown how to establish relationship with dom element, version 0.15x

Tags: javascript, webrtc, sip, sipjs

I don't kown how to establish relationship with dom element, version 0.15x,
in 0.06x version it's `options.media.render` ,but what's it in 0.15x

```
<div class="chat-sip">
  <video id="remoteVideo"></video>
  <video id="localVideo" muted="muted"></video>
  <button (click)="push()">push</button>
  <button id="endCall">End Call</button>
</div>
```

```
var userAgent = new UA();
var session = userAgent.invite("example@onsip.com");
```

resolved see this [Attach Media](https://sipjs.com/guides/attach-media/)

Comment: Which javascript library are you using?

Comment: sip.js,I solved the problem above,but do you know how to define custom-data when create UserAgent so that the person being invited could get some infomation from the person who created the session

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'SIP')
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (sip.js:46:15)
    at sip.js:47:3
webpackUniversalModuleDefinition @ sip.js:46
(anonymous) @ sip.js:47
 I m getting this error